# Пустые переменные в цикле с list после json_decode()

Tags: php, ajax

Передаю так массив:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "csv.php",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: "section=" + JSON.stringify(section),
})
```

Приходит так:

```
Array
(
    [section] => [{"link":....
}
```

Делаю:

```
$section = json_decode($_POST['section'], true);
```

$section после json_decode():

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://vm1.culture.ru/upload/uploaded/0002300176/0002300176.jpg
        [filename] => 0002300176.jpg
        [name] => Ваза, автор: Врубель Михаил Александрович
        [author] => Врубель Михаил Александрович
        [material] => Глина
        [scale] => Вазы, Врубель
        [date] => 
1890-1918 гг.
        [museum] => Федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение культуры  «Государственный историко-художественный и литературный Музей-заповедник "Абрамцево"
        [city] => Высота - 48 см, диаметр основания - 16 см, диаметр верха - 12 см
        [notation] => 




    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [link] => http://vm1.culture.ruundefined
        [filename] => vm1.culture.ruundefined
        [name] => Ваза, автор: Врубель М.А
        [author] => Врубель М.А
        [material] => Глина
        [scale] => Врубель, Вазы
        [date] => 
1890 – 1918 гг.
        [museum] => Федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение культуры  «Государственный историко-художественный и литературный Музей-заповедник "Абрамцево"
        [city] => H 40,5 см, d (осн.) 23 см;  d горла 19 см
        [notation] => 




    )

...
```

Но вот дальнейший вывод ни к чему не приводит:

```
foreach ($section as list($link, $filename, $name, $author, $material, $scale, $date, $museum, $city, $notation)) {
... - все переменные из list пусты
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

> В PHP 5.5 была добавлена возможность обхода массива массивов с распаковкой вложенного массива в переменные цикла, передав list() в качестве значения.

http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach.list

Вероятно у вас версия PHP ниже 5.5.

Comment: Я проверял это, но нет: версия 5.6.12.

Comment: И list в foreach как функция работает.